# Problem with all flash uploaders, on all sites

Tags: flash, flash-player

This just started happening to me, and Im not sure why. Every single flash uploader online seems to upload files virtually instantly, and large file (400mb+) upload in a few seconds, but of course the data isn't actually sent that fast, so the uploaders just stall at 100%.

This doesn't just happen on my own sites, but every single site that uses flash uploading.

I reinstalled Flash, and still having same problems.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, it was AVG's "link scanner". After I disabled it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find the solution by looking at what Flash is doing when you upload files. Try looking at the output from Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: not much help there :(